# Having problems with database

Tags: c++

In my c++ program, I'm having problems with my program where I am running too many things through the database at once and am getting an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: perhaps you should wait for each `this.ptoDataService.update(this.ptoData[i]);` to complete, before sending the next.

Comment: what does `this.ptoDataService.update(this.ptoData[i]);` return?

Comment: If you can make the ```update``` function call some callback after results are returned, you could make a recursive callback to a function, where you would pass a list of items, if list is empty return, if not then update the first entry and call the same function minus the updated value in the callback

Comment: It would be better to collect the changes and send all updates at once, instead of making a single request for each item in `ptoData`, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: "don't believe it's possible" because of?

Comment: Perhaps you should post your server side sql code that does the update? Don't think angular code will resolve your SQL issue. Something in your sql queries is causing a slow down before other query can execute. I would suggest run SQL Profile Trace to find out the cause of your deadlock and try to resolve it.

Comment: Is your other part of your code using the same IHttpActionResult PutPTOData? If it is, it's probably not using the same logic as what your angular code is trying to do, you are trying to update 1000's of items inside a for loop within a same transaction boundary.

Comment: @12seconds yeah, it is and it's not using the same logic as what my current code is trying to do. I was just stating that while it probably needs revised to be able to handle updating 1000's of items, it works for simple things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have updated your code with server side code. Here's one way you can resolve your dead lock.

First you need to understand by default Entity framework isolation level for transaction is **Serializable**. Here's some more information on [SQL server Isolation levels.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

It states that for Serializable:

- No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes.

So what you need to do is change your EF transaction scope isolation level to snapshot example:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new 
TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel= IsolationLevel.Snapshot }))
{
    // do something with EF here
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recordPayroll(): void {
  return Observable.of(this.ptoData).mergeMap(ptoDataItem => { 
    if (this.ptoDataItem.date < this.date && this.ptoDataItem.type != "Uncharged") {
      this.ptoDataItem.inPR = true;
      return this.ptoDataService.update(this.ptoDataItem);
    } 
    return Observable.empty();
  }
}
```

No guarantees this will work. I don't use TS myself and are not used to RxJS.